# Understanding tuple output from groups() method after re.match()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, character-class

I am working with regular expressions and am struggling to understand a particular output.

### Case 1:

```
>>> m = re.match("(abc)+", "abc")
>>> m.groups()
('abc',)
```

### Case 2:

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
>>> m.groups()
('c',)
```

In Case 1 above, I do understand how `m.groups()` returns `('abc',)` (a tuple with the matched string for group 1, the only group in the RE).

However, in Case 2 above, where I put 'abc' in the RE inside a character class as `[abc]`, I do not understand why does `m.groups()` return `('c',)`. I would have still expected the same tuple returned as Case 1, i.e. `('abc',)`

Could anyone please help me understand why does `m.groups()` return `('c',)` in Case 2.

Comment: `(abc)` means a group containing `a` followed by `b` followed by `c`. `([abc])` means a group containing `a` OR `b` OR `c`

Comment: The quantifier `+` is on the `group`, not the characters.